# mongodb how log number of queries from given time

Tags: mongodb

currently I'm optimizing API in project which I work for.
Project is using mongodb DB.

I would like to check some how how many queries was on DB from given time.

If I for example at 11.00 will start some API call which will query a lot DB, I would like to see how many queries was at this 11.00 ( of course locally when application is not doing anything besides this api call ).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) for your database and set profiling level (2 will profile all database operations, including indexing). E.g.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Database profile will be logged to system.profile collection. You can query this collection to get required data. E.g. following query will return total number of database queries since 11:00 AM of 30th October:

```
db.system.profile.find({ts : {$gt: ISODate('2013-10-30T11:00:00Z')}}).count()
```

You can filter results by collection:

```
db.system.profile.find({ ns: 'database.collectionName', 
                         ts : {$gt: ISODate('2013-10-30T11:00:00Z')}}).count()
```